# Good program design/best practice to avoid multiple redundant checks (eg. in C++)

Tags: c++

Suppose I have some functions (eg. `method1()` and `method2()`), and each of these functions should only be performed if a some condition(s) are met (for this simplistic example, call this a check against a boolean). To isolate the conditional check, I place the check inside each function - eg

```
void method1()
{
    if (bDoSomething) {
        doSomething1();
        doSomething2();
    }
}

void method2()
{
    if (bDoSomething) {
        doSomething1();
        doSomething3();
    }
}
```

However, the `doSomethingN()` functions can also be called on their own, outside of `method1()` and `method2()`, so I then add the conditional check into each `doSomethingN()` function- eg.

```
void doSomething1() {
    if (bDoSomething) {
        doWork1();
    }
}
```

Also, suppose `method1()` and `method2()` can be called from within the same function - eg.

```
void func1() {
    method1();
    method2();
}
```

This results in multiple checks for the same condition when calling `func1()`, `method1()` or `method2()`. What would be a better way of doing this to avoid the multiple checks ?

Are there any good resources on how best to design/structure a program to minimise this kind of thing ?

Comment: && or (hilariously) ||

--- group relevant evaluations together

Comment: You need to identify where the check makes best sense. Should the function be aware of the check or the outside world calling the function check. In-case the function has no responsibility for the check keep it out and let it not burden with things not related to it. And if the check fails inside the function, it should have relevant return values to indicate success of failure

Comment: I thought of asking the same question for a long time. Null-reference checks, array length > 0 checks and so on - my code is full of them.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the concrete details of your issue.. One thing you could do is to put the checks within the `doSomething` functions.

```
void doSomething1() {
    if(!bDoSomething) return;

    ....
}
```

You don't need to check the conditions in the outer functions, Just call the appropriate functions and they will execute if needed. You could still leave it in for self-documentation purposes.

It is also possible that your code is a lot more convoluted than is needed. To diagnose that you need more details and the big picture.

p.s You can try my style of checking, i.e return-if-negative, rather than process-if-positive, this might make the code a little cleaner sometimes, but reducing the indentation level.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have two classes: `Private` and `Captain`. Lets use them in such a way that `Captain`s command `Private`s. What `Captain`s want, `Private`s do. Let's have an illustration:

```
void Captain::HaveSomethingDone() {
   if(AmIAtAnAdvantage()) {
       for(Private& p : m_privates) {
           p.Attack();
       }
   }
   else if(IsSituationStalemate()) {
       for(Private& p : m_privates) {
           p.Hold();
       }
   }
   else if(IsALosingBattle()) {
       for(Private& p : m_privates) {
           p.Retreat();
       }
   }
}
```

In the above example, the `Private`s do *unconditionally* what the `Captain` wants because the `Captain` knows what it's doing. In this way we have *clear(er) separation of concerns*.

Another one, now for methods. Take this as an example:

```
void DoSomething() {
    if(ShouldPrint()) {
        Print();
    }

    if(ShouldCleanUp()) {
        CleanUp();
    }

    // ...
}
```

In the above example, `DoSomething()` knows what it should do. It is the one who decides what it should do. The `Print()` and `CleanUp()` methods therefore should unconditionally do what it's meant to do. `Print()` prints. `CleanUp()` cleans up.

Now contemplate.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to avoid multiple conditional checks would be implement State design pattern in your code. This design pattern just allows you to use code as State machine, meaning depending upon the state of your object state you can call desired method. you can get more information over here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess your check is pretty heavy, otherwise I would not worry about double call, because your code will be much CLEANER.

I have two things in mind:

- Caching the first check result somewhere in your class.
- Making caller object, which could be created only when your condition is true.

Something like that:

```
class ConditionalCaller
{
public:
    void Method1();
    void Method2();
};

class YourClass
{
public:
    ConditionalCaller* GetCaller()
    {
        if (CanGetCaller())
            return new ConditionalCaller();

        return NULL;
    }

    bool CanGetCaller();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different cases:

1. `method1` and `method2` are private, you can control where they are called and you can guarantee that all pre conditions are checked. In this case you can avoid these tests in these methods.
2. `method1` and `method2` are public and you document that as a precondition several conditions have to be met (like in containers in std).
3. `method1` amd `method2` check their precondition and respond accordingly (throwing and exception, do nothing, ...).
4. you create checked and unchecked versions of your methods (mixing other variants) and distinguish them via different names `*_checked` or additional parameters (like in notthrow new).

But remember Scott Meyers: Make Interfaces Easy to Use Correctly and Hard to Use Incorrectly.

So you have make your decision and document it.